# 403 forbidden on one page only

Tags: categories, slug

I can't access http://www.mysite.com.hr/biljke/
The only error i get is

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /biljke/ on this server.

This is regular hierarchical category for post. I have tried:

1. deactivating all plugins (removed category slug also, so url should be http://www.mysite.com.hr/category/biljke but it still redirects me to http://www.mysite.com.hr/biljke ).
2. I have deleted htaccess file and refreshed the permalinks so Wordpress can generate default one.
3. I have uploaded empty functions.php
4. If I change the slug of category to something else (biljke1) it works, but it won't make sense so I can't let it be.

What else can I try to find out what is the cause of this problem? It is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the folder 'biljke' exist on the server by any chance?? i.e. do you have wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes AND biljke as folders in your Wordpress root?

[Reposted as an answer so it can be accepted, probably should have done that in the first place without trying to comment!]